# How to implement a follow author (or user) function?

Tags: 7, emails, notifications

Is it possible to implement a **Follow** button for authors of posts in Drupal 7, so that users can:

- Follow any one they wish, and
- Be notified about the new posts of those authors.

This sounds like '*Mashable Follow button*' for authors.

Do you have any suggestions about how to implement this?

Answer (score 5):

## Minimal solution

The [Notifications](http://www.drupal.org/project/notifications) module currently only has an [Alfa version](https://www.drupal.org/node/1360848) for D7 (which is this question is about), which dates from Dec 2011.

Therefor, use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module as an alternative. So that users can "flag" authors they want to "follow". You'd want to use a flag related to entity "users", which is a non-global flag. Probably defined with a label like "Follow Author" (to 'flag' an author) and "Unfollow Author" (to undo a previously flagged Author).

Combine this with using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to send eMails whenever content gets updated by some author. Whereas the eMails are sent to all users who "flagged" that author (= the users who indicated they wanted to "follow" that author). If you'd only want to send such eMails for a subset of content that's being updated (eg only for selected content types), then it's just a matter of adding an appropriate extra "condition" to your rule.

## Improved solution

Optionally you may also want to consider the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module for more options in the area of sending some type of notifications. For this, you need a flag like described above (say with machine name `follow`).

On top of that you need a ***Message type*** and a custom ***Rule***, both are detailed below. And you probably also want to add a custom ***View*** of those messages.

#### Message type

Below is an export of "a" Message type that you could use to get started (by simply importing it in your own site). It defines the message to be created when a user is flagged and it actually works together with the custom rule below. This message type has machine name `user_following`, and uses a replacement token like `@following_user` (adapt both to fit your needs, eg change `@following_user` to `@user_who_flagged` if you prefer):

```
{
  "name" : "user_following",
  "description" : "User following",
  "argument_keys" : [ "@following_user" ],
  "argument" : [],
  "category" : "message_type",
  "data" : {
    "token options" : { "clear" : 0 },
    "purge" : { "override" : 0, "enabled" : 0, "quota" : "", "days" : "" }
  },
  "language" : "",
  "arguments" : null,
  "message_text" : { "und" : [
      {
        "value" : "@following_user started following [message:user:name]",
        "format" : "plain_text",
        "safe_value" : "\u003Cp\u003E@following_user started following [message:user:name]\u003C\/p\u003E\n"
      }
    ]
  },
  "rdf_mapping" : []
}
```

This Message type (compare to a *Content type* ...) will be used to create Messages (compare to *Nodes*) that will look as in this example:

> Hillary.Trump started following Donald.Clinton

To avoid confusion, note that `[message:user:name]` in the message type sample above is the user **to** which the Message is targeted, not the flagging user!

#### Custom Rule

Here is a rule (in Rules Export format) which creates a message when a user is flagged:

```
{ "rules_somebody_started_following_you" : {
    "LABEL" : "Somebody started following you",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "user" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "flag" ],
    "ON" : { "flag_flagged_follow" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "message",
            "param_type" : "user_following",
            "param_user" : [ "flagged-user" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "entity-created:arguments:following-user" ],
          "value" : "[site:current-user]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some more details about this rule:

- Its purpose is to deliver a message (using the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module) to a user being flagged (using the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module).
- It is triggered after a user is flagged with the flag with machine name `follow`.
- It creates a Message with machine name `user_following`.
- It makes a variable with machine name `following_user` available as a replacement token for the message to be created ... so that the "flagging user" (= `[site:current-user]` when the flagging happens) can also be included in the message to be created.

#### Custom view

With the above rule and message type, you'll have "messages" that get created ... "*So what?*" you may think. Well, since all this is entity API based, you can create a custom view (using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)) to visualize these messages, e.g. shown via a path like `/user/nid/messages`. Whereas the only limitation for such Views is your own imagination (you could even create the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) about those Messages (eg by originating user, by date, etc).

## Additional info

If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework). Possibly also the similar [set of 8 video tutorials](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-flag) about the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module.

For more details about the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module, refer to some interesting [Use Cases](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180149) detailed within its [Community Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145). And/or checkout the video introduction "[Your Drupal site can talk](https://vimeo.com/63919900)" (if you want you can fast forward to about 03:30 where it really starts).

**Note**: this approach can be used also for any type of users (not just for "authors").

Answer (score 3):

The [Notifications](http://drupal.org/project/notifications) module provides this functionality. Enable the **User Subscriptions** and **Notifications UI** sub-modules of it.

> This is a complete Subscriptions/Notifications Framework aiming at extendability and scalability. It allows any number of plug-ins defining new event types or subscription types or a different user interface.

Comment: Development on Notifications seemed to have stopped for D7, maybe try Message http://drupal.org/project/message