# Where is the Drupal Syslog module log file in Cpanel?

Tags: 7, database

I disable dblog module and want to enable syslog module instead of it.
After enabling that ,I can't see any drupal Log in error_log file in cpanel .

what is reason? where is Drupal log file for cpanel shared hostings?

My drupal version : 7

thank you

Comment: Hi, the location of you server's syslog isn't something Drupal has any influence over, it's something you'll need to ask your hosting provider or system administrator about.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned on the [documentation page for the syslog module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/core/modules/syslog/overview), syslog is generally not suitable for shared hosting.

This is because it requires access to server level functionality and configuration that you aren't allowed to access on shared hosting.

Comment: Hm, never realized that "issue" about Syslog (or should I say never saw that phrase on the link you mentioned?) ...

Answer (score 0):

IMO the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module could be a perfect alternative, for situations where "syslog" cannot be used. Using this module, you can create your own custom "*Events logging*" (to register things that happened in a site). Specific to this question here, I'd create a so called "Message type" that contains the actual data to be logged.

You could even track things like updates to nodes, i.e. how data looked like before and after they got updated, a kind of "light" revisioning (only for those node attributes you want to know about).

About *Message types*: think of them as equivalent to Content types, whereas you create messages (instead of nodes) of a specific Message type (instead of Content type).

#### Rules integration

A really interesting facility of the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module is its perfect integration with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. Have a look at the answer to "[How to implement a follow author (or user) function?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40351/how-to-implement-a-follow-author-or-user-function/170748#170748)" for way more details on that.

As an example, here is a (rather basic) custom rule:

- a Rules Event like "Before saving a new node", of "After updating an existing node" (or variations of these events).
- a Rules Action to "Create a message" (of a selected Message type).

That's really it ...

#### Example included in Commerce Kickstart

A great sample of this can be found in [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart), which uses the [Commerce Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message) module, to create such "*Events logging*". In that case in the format of an Order History, as shown in [this screenprint](https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/commerce_message%20history.png) (from this module's project page).

#### Replicate/replace the Activity module

Should you want to do so, it seems perfectly possible to build a view (report) that contains the data similar to what you can do with the [Activity](https://www.drupal.org/project/activity) module as shown in [this screenprint](https://www.drupal.org/files/images/Activity%20%7C%20activity2.png) (from this module's project page).

#### More info about the Message module

The [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module is an amazing module, it is fully entity based, which implies that it perfectly (out of the box) integrates with modules such as [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

Though there is ***not a lot of documentation about it*** (which is what makes it a hidden D7 gem ...). A possible way to get started with it, and to get an idea of the kind of things it can be used for, is to have a look at the answers to:

- [How to create a basic message - notifications system displaying a real time message counter badge?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68867/how-to-create-a-basic-message-notifications-system-displaying-a-real-time-mess/210869#210869)
- [How to show message view containing own and following activity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222788/how-to-show-message-view-containing-own-and-following-activity/222800#222800)
- [How to integrate messaging into a custom module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202299/how-to-integrate-messaging-into-a-custom-module/202314#202314)
- [Is there a simple way to notify users about new posts on the site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/116540/is-there-a-simple-way-to-notify-users-about-new-posts-on-the-site/221661#221661)

**Tutorials:**

- [What is Drupal's Message Stack and how do its modules work together?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/105)
- [How to allow users to manage their own Message Stack messages?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/82)
- [What's the purpose of "Replacement tokens" of a Message type?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/109)