# Is there any log or receipt or anything that message was sent to someone?

Tags: 7, emails

I'm in a situation where I'm supposed to testify (= proof) that a message (confirmation) was sent from our site (using Drupal 7).

Is it possible to see it from anywhere? Does it register into hosting provider or something like that?

I tried looking at the log files on the server, but they didn't include anything regarding this message; the Drupal system log was one month ahead that time when the message was sent.

A custom message (confirmation) is sent with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) when user makes an order and registers as user (of which all is done via customized "Add node" form).

Comment: _Does it register into hosting provider or something like that?_ that entirely depends on your hosting provider and the mailsysteem you have in use. But most of system mails are shown in the recent log messages of the Drupal site itself.

Comment: What type of message/email was it?  IOW, which system email, or which module did it come from.  You tagged Commerce; was it a Commerce email in particular?

Comment: Added details above

Comment: So effectively you need to find out if a message was sent 2 months ago?

Comment: There is nothing in Drupal that would allow you to go back months in time. There might be some log on your server. But that depends on your server configuration and would be off-topic here.

Comment: Please explain why in the original version of your question you added the "drupal-commerce" tag (which got removed in revision 3 of your question by a moderator, probably because nowhere in your question it was clear you are actually using Drupal Commerce). If that's the case, then add "and Drupal Commerce", right after "Drupal 7". And if you're indeed using Drupal Commerce, did you yes/no start from Commerce Kickstart? If that's the case, then the first phrase in the prior comment might be wrong ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about server logs which aren't handled by Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

It won't help to go back in time, but for similar requests in the future I recommend you to have a look at the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module, which is part of the [Message Stack](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145). Read on for more details ...

#### Create a Message archive (audit trail)

By using the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module, you automagically also create an archive of all Messages. Which is very handy in cases such as when a user claims to never have received some eMail. In such cases, think about how you'd proof that some eMail was mailed somewhere in the past ... as compared to using [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) and just bring up that message again ...

A typical scenario (as in the question here) that would be prevented by using the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module:

> I tried to look at the log files at server but they didn't include anything regardins this message. Also the Drupal system log was one month ahead that time when the message was sent.

#### Message stack

These are the basic components and dependencies of it:

[image]

For this question only the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module would be needed (not the other Message-related modules). But first, to explain the above picture, some more details about the Message-related modules (=quotes are from the module's project page):

- [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message):

  > The Message module is the core of the message stack. It enables logging and displaying system events in a number of different use cases. Events that are recorded over time are sometimes call activity streams. Exportable messages subtypes can be created for different use cases with custom fields and display (view) modes.
- [Message Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_notify).

  > This module provides a method for sending a message via a notifier plugin. Message Notify comes with plugins for email and SMS and may be extended to other transport mechanisms as required.
- [Message Subscribe](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_subscribe).

  > With this module, users who subscribe to content will be notified when events occur that involve that content. The module leverages the Flag module, which provides a subscribe functionality to users.

#### Distributions / modules using Messages

Quite a few popular Drupal distributions already adopted to this Message Stack, [Open Atrium](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium) is one of them.

A great sample of this can be found in [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart), which uses the [Commerce Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message) module, to create such "*Events logging*". In that case in the format of an Order History, as shown in [this screenprint](https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/commerce_message%20history.png) (from this module's project page).

If you'd rather look at an existing module as an example, then checkout the 7.x-4.x version of the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer) and its **Answers Notification** sub-module. This sub-module allows logged in users to subscribe to selected questions, so that they receive notifications (using the Message Stack) when Questions receive Answers.

#### Combining Rules and Message

Moreover, by using the technique of ***Replacement tokens***, it's possible to create your own [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message)-"tokens" using ... [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)! If these *Replacement Tokens* don't mean anything to you (ie you don't understand what they are really about), then head over to the answer to [What's the purpose of "Replacement tokens" of a Message type?](http://drupal.placeto.be/node/109) for (way) more details on that.

As an example, here is a (rather basic) custom rule:

- a Rules Event like "Before saving a new node", of "After updating an existing node" (or variations of these events).
- a Rules Action to "Create a message" (of a selected Message type).

That's really it ...

A really interesting facility of the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module is its perfect integration with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. Have a look at the answer to "[How to implement a follow author (or user) function?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40351/how-to-implement-a-follow-author-or-user-function/170748#170748)" for way more details on that.

Yet another sample that could be a perfect fit (= a quote from the question ...):

> I'm using Drupal 7 and custom message(confirmation) is sent with Rules when user has made an order and registered as user (of which all is done via customized "Add node" form).

#### You might be lucky

The prior quote got [added to the question afterwards](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/228381/2). And possibly explains also why you tagged your question with the [drupal-commerce](/questions/tagged/drupal-commerce) tag (removed in [revision 3](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/228381/3) by a mod).

So if you're lucky your site might already use the [Commerce Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message) module, in which case you already might have such audit trail (which you don't know about). Just use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to search what you're looking for.

If you don't use that module yet, then hurry to get it enabled for similar requests in the future.

#### Possible alternative for syslog

The [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module is also a possible alternative for the Syslog module (included in Drupal core). For example in situations like this one (= quote from "[Syslog module overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/core/modules/syslog/overview)"):

> It is not suitable for shared hosting environments.

#### More info about the Message module

The [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module is an amazing module, it is fully entity based, which implies that it perfectly (out of the box) integrates with modules such as [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

Though there is ***not a lot of documentation about it*** (which is what makes it a hidden D7 gem ...). A possible way to get started with it, and to get an idea of the kind of things it can be used for, is to have a look at the answers to:

- [How to create a basic message - notifications system displaying a real time message counter badge?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68867/how-to-create-a-basic-message-notifications-system-displaying-a-real-time-mess/210869#210869)
- [How to show message view containing own and following activity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222788/how-to-show-message-view-containing-own-and-following-activity/222800#222800)
- [How to integrate messaging into a custom module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202299/how-to-integrate-messaging-into-a-custom-module/202314#202314)
- [Is there a simple way to notify users about new posts on the site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/116540/is-there-a-simple-way-to-notify-users-about-new-posts-on-the-site/221661#221661)

**Tutorials:**

- [What is Drupal's Message Stack and how do its modules work together?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/105)
- [How to allow users to manage their own Message Stack messages?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/82)

Comment: That seems a lot of overhead for validating if one mail was sent... Or i misunderstood the question...

Comment: This would certainly make it a lot easier and most of all it would protect our rights and obligate customers.

Comment: @Neograph734 : did you see the additional comment from OPer? Ie "***This would make it a lot easier ...***". True this implies extra overhead, but if the site is critical enough (eg an ecommerce site ...), this kind of audit trail is, IMO, simply a must. Because without it, you risk to run in problems as illustrated in the question here.

Comment: If the Drupal database log was ahead one month, try enabling core's syslog module (in addition you can disable the database log). Database log only keeps X (default 1000) lines. Syslog keeps everything. This will not make you go back in time either, but allows you to scroll back through all system log messages.

Comment: In fact the Syslog module is enabled along with the database log. However, it only shows the visits from IP address to the checkout/order number page that belongs to customer. That is at least something to backup for us. Although when we dunning for the first time the customer admitted ordering the service and also promised to pay it. We'll see where this leads... But at least now I know what to use in the future.