# How to create a rule and inject mysql code?

Tags: 7, database, rules

Can I create a rule on my drupal 7 website and that rule will:

Whenever a user is logged in (only logged in users can see this content) and a certain content is clicked I want to write a mysql update statement to my  database. The user name of that person and what content was clicked.

I know I can execute PHP code for my action but not sure if I need to somehow convert mysql and php together? please if anyone knows and could give a fairly detailed instructions I would appreciate it greatly!

Comment: You should read [Rule's Developer Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/878718)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a security breach in your site (logged in user is not bullet proof and relies maybe a bit too much on trust of user's sense of responsability considering keeping strong password and clean browsers, closing sessions...), I would suggest to look into the existing statistics module and match the objective by configuration and customisation. It is not possible to give you the right answer because it depends on a lot of variables, but here are a few links to dig and find your solution:

Statistics documentation:

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/core/modules/statistics/overview,

Google Analytics modules:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics
- https://www.drupal.org/project/ga_push
- https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_et

I think you could do pretty much what you want with GA + Rules: https://www.drupal.org/node/37694,

Other statistics modules:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/tether_stats,
- https://www.drupal.org/project/jstats,
- https://www.drupal.org/project/events_log_track

EDIT : Also you could use views to generate an output of the necessary information and an export in csv to make it even better

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use PHP within some custom rule, and then include your SQL statements. But that requires PHP code to be stored in your Drupal database ... which is ***bad*** (repeat: ***bad***).

I recommend you to not go that path. But instead you should use the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module, to create the equivalent of those database records you want to create.

Have a look at [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/241408/39516) to "[How to create audit trails/order revisions?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/241375/39516)", which is like a variation of your question, and which explains how the Message module integrates with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to get this to work. Did I mention zero custom (PHP) code?